# openGL - batch rendering - object matrices/etc update

Tags: opengl, matrix, render

I'm trying to wrap my head around some of the openGL render options.

For now my sudo code goes in something like this:

```
void paint() {
    ...
    for (auto &obj:objList) {
        obj.draw(matrix)
    }
}


void draw(matrix &m){
    shaderProgram->bind();
    meshVao->bind();
    meshVertex->bind();
    meshIndices->bind();
    shaderProgram->setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", m * getObjTrans());
    shaderProgram->setUniformValue("un_color", QVector4D(1, 1, 1, 1));
    shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("position");
    shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer("position", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mMeshData->mIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

Now this just binds every object 1 by 1, sets its matrix, and draw it. Its fairly inneficient with lets say 5-20k+objects.

Now I was reading lately and from what I can say I could also load all objects data in to 1-2 VBO under 1 VAO and then draw them all in 1 call.  So if I take all indices in to 1 vector and all vertex in to 1 vector, I can then bind just these 2 vbo objects and draw all objects in 1 call. The probem I try to understand is, how do I pass a matrix for each object in the vectors?
In function above, I pass a matrix to each obj before drawing it, but if all my objects are in 1-2 vectors, how am I to pass matrix to them separately?

A rough last second idea would be to create a vector matrix. And pass all matrices in to that 1 vector and pass that in to the fragment/pixel shader. Then have an offset counter in there and every next object render, just do `matrix[offset*16]` and this will give me matrix for that object. Once thats there all I need is `matrix[offset*16]` until `matrix[offset*16+16]` to get all 16 floats to create matrix and use to draw the object?

Is this the right direction?

Comment: Why do you have to install the shader program (`shaderProgram->bind();`) for each object. Can't you use the same program for all the objects? Why do you have to bind the verices (`meshVertex->bind();`) and indices (`meshIndices->bind();`) for each object? Isn't it sufficient to bind the VAO? All what has to be done to draw a mesh should be: 1. bind the VAO (`meshVao->bind()`); 2. set the uniforms (model matrix, color) or bind SSBO; 3. bind textures; 4. draw the mesh.

Comment: Hey, interesting thanks! did not know that, Will do tests. However with 10-20-50k objects binding that many vaos, is still a "hassle". So a way to batch it all in to 1 VAO should be a better solution?

Comment: @Rabbid76 so I // away the binding of vertex and indices, but then I get error, I'm using QT for my openGL wrapper, so I think I need to bind them all in the order I did. Else I just get crash.

Comment: If I see all objects and rotate camera around them, then yes. I need to draw them all. Its big data set. They don't move per frame, unless usermoves them himself in which case I can do some optimizations. But still, need more performance than 4-10fps I got now

Comment: Is instancing an option for you? Do you draw the same object at different transformations, colours and such (write those into buffers and use `gl_InstanceID` in the shader)? Or are there really 50k unique meshes?

Comment: 50k unique meshes sadly. The number very between 10 meshes and 100k+ or so.

Comment: Are you looking for Uniform Buffer Objects or similar techniques?

Comment: Your idea then makes sense: have one (static) attribute identify which vertex belongs to which object and one buffer where you store your matrices, buffer your model transformations and draw all your objects in one draw call. That's one way to reduce the amount of synchronisation needed between cpu and gpu. Keep [LoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) in mind if you're actually drawing too many faces (measure your render time) though combining the first approach with LoD is going to be tricky i.e. requires you to update the index buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Approaching Zero Driver Overhead (ADZO) techniques](https://de.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/approaching-zero-driver-overhead). In particular, have a look at [`ARB_multi_draw_indirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_multi_draw_indirect.txt) (in core since OpenGL 4.3) and [`ARB_shader_draw_parameters`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_draw_parameters.txt) (in core since OpenGL 4.6). The latter will give you a `gl_DrawID` input for your vertex shader which can be used to index into UBOs, SSBOs or TBOs holding per-object data like model matrices, texture array layer, materials or whatever.

For cases where `gl_DrawID` is not available (GL 4.6 support isn't universal currently), there is a relatively clever workaround: [`http://www.g-truc.net/post-0518.html`](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0518.html). By using `glglVertexAttribDivisor` of 1, a single attribute value is used for all data of one instance - and a non-instanced draw call is just defined to be equivalent to an instanced draw-call with an instance count of `1` - so you get the same value for all vertices in that particular draw call.That way, you only need a relatively small buffer with just one ID per object, you do not have to replicate it for every vertex of the object. And with multi draw indirect call, you can specify many of those with just a singe actual draw call.